# all_sequences table/relation not found?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am not able to query the "all_sequences" table in my database.

Do I need to give any grants to the owner/userID to resolve this issue?

Due to this issue, During server startup I get the below error from hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto validate:

```
ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator - HHH000300: Could not complete schema validation
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "all_sequences" does not exist
```

Comment: Where in the [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find `all_sequences`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am new to postgres. I thought that all_sequences table will be available by default. Right?

Comment: No, that is an Oracle specific view, it's not something that is part of the SQL standard - if in doubt you should consult the manual, all system tables and views are documented there: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html

Answer (score 6):

You should update your hibernate.cfg.xml with the following property:

`<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>`